# Printing Nodes from a Linked List

Tags: python, printing, linked-list

I am having an issue printing elements from a Linked List. I have tried creating a `toString` function in my `Node` class, I have used the `str()` constructor, `__str__()`, plain ole `<object>.data`, and lastly `__repr__` (at the moment this is not printing at all it's stuck in an infinite loop. My code is below

```
class Node:
  #default constructor
  def __init__(self, data = None):
    self.data = data
    self.next = None

  def toString(self):
    return str(self.data)
    
class SLinkedList():
  def __init__(self):
    self.head = None

  def addToEnd(self, newData):
    newNode = Node(newData)
    
    if self.head is None:
      self.head = newNode
      return 
      
    last = self.head
    while(last.next):
      last = last.next
    last.next = newNode


  def listprint(self):
      printval = self.head
      while printval is not None:
         #print (printval.toString())
         #print(printval.data)
         #print(str(printval.data))
         print(printval.data.__str__())
         #print(printval.__repr__())
        
         printval = printval.next

List = SLinkedList()
e1 = Node("Mon")
e2 = Node("Tues")
e3 = Node("Wed")

print("adding to list")
List.addToEnd(e1)
List.addToEnd(e2)  
List.addToEnd(e3)

print("printing list ")
List.listprint()
```

Lastly this is my output from all the attempts except for this line `print( printval.__repr__)` because it just gets stuck in a loop doesn't print anything

```
<__main__.Node object at 0x7f4d4c6abdc0>
<__main__.Node object at 0x7f4d4c6abd60>
<__main__.Node object at 0x7f4d4c6abd00>
```

I also was reading this article: [pretty print linked list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pretty-print-linked-list-in-python/), and also watched this video [Python: Printing a Linked List](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=53YG_eum-EE&t=59s). I still don't see where I went wrong.

How can I get my `listprint` method to work so that it prints the contents of the list? e.g.

```
Mon
Tues
Wed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not create a new node in `addToEnd`, since you are already passing in Node instances.

`newNode = Node(newData)` should be removed; directly use `newData` instead. Otherwise, you are creating new nodes whose `data` is another node rather than a string.

```py
def addToEnd(self, newData):
    if self.head is None:
      self.head = newData
      return 
    last = self.head
    while(last.next):
      last = last.next
    last.next = newData
```

Comment: See the code working [here](https://ideone.com/u02JVv).

Comment: Should probably rename the argument to `newNode` to make it clear what it should be. If I saw an argument named `newData`, I'd expect it to contain _data_.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of `addToEnd` expects the *data* to add to the end of the linked list as the `newData` argument. With this data, the linked list creates a new node for you. You do not need to pass the nodes themselves to the `addToEnd` method.

Keeping this in mind, you should use your list like so:

```
List = SLinkedList()

List.addToEnd("Mon")
List.addToEnd("Tues")  
List.addToEnd("Wed")

List.listprint()
```

which prints the contents of the list as expected:

```
Mon
Tues
Wed
```

Note that you do not need to call `__str__` method of the argument you pass to `print()` -- it does so implicitly:

```
    def listprint(self):
       curr_node = self.head
       while curr_node:
           print(curr_node.data)
           curr_node = curr_node.next
```

Note that I renamed the `printval` variable to `curr_node` because it holds the *current node* whose value you are printing. It is a good practice to give your variables names that reflect what they are/do, because it makes your code more readable and therefore easier to debug.